# Bath tub paint coming off

Tags: paint, bathtub

My cast iron bath tub paint is chipping off and the underlying material (is it epoxy, not sure) is being exposed. Is this something to be concerned about? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is paint or is it ceramic?

Comment: I may be wrong. How can I check?

Comment: It's more a cosmetic issue than a problem to be worried about.

Comment: Ok good to know. But it is increasing. How can I prevent it from increasing and how do I fix it cosmetically?